# Biblatex 2.8a biblatex chem-angew style without square brackets

Tags: biblatex

I'm new to LaTeX and decided to write my PhD thesis with it (pdflatex.exe, TexStudio2.6.6, Win7x64).

Here we go. the angew. chem. style is usually without square brackets in the text. how can i modify the chem-angew.bbx, so that i get rid of those brackets in `\cite{1}` resulting in [1]?

I know that I have to redefine some command but a lack of knowledge does not allow me to complete the task. Could anyone help me?

here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=chem-angew,sortcites=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\cite}{\supercite}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

We are citing \cite{A01,C03} and \cite{B02} and \cite{A01,B02,C03}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility — as I think the  `superbracket` command is used only for citations: add this to your preamble:

```
\let\mkbibsuperbracket\mkbibsuperscript
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to alter the declaration for `\supercite`, which for the *Angewandte* style includes brackets as standard:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript] % Change here
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}
```

Comment: ok, it works, thank you very much! i would like to understand your modifications done to the code. can you please provide the unchanged code with brackets?

Comment: about angew. chem style i was wrong. it is in brackets as standard. sorry for the wrong statement. anyway, nice to have this code.